# Role of Maxwell's stress tensor in the conservation of momentum of an EM wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, poynting-vector

**Defining the Wave:**

Let's assume an electromagnetic wave exists in the form

$\vec{E}(x,y,z,t) = \vec{E}_0 \, cos(kx-\omega t)$

$\vec{B}(x,y,z,t) = \vec{B}_0 \, cos(kx-\omega t)$

**How the wave interacts with particles:**

Let's say for example my proton is at the origin $$(x,y,z) = (0,0,0)$$

What are the associated electric and magnetic fields attached to that specific point in space?

$\vec{E}(x,y,z,t) = \vec{E}_0 \, \cos(\omega t)$

$\vec{B}(x,y,z,t) = \vec{B}_0 \, \cos(\omega t)$

Force on the charge :

$\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} +\vec{V}×\vec{B})$

As $(\vec{V} × \vec{B})<< \vec{E}$

$\vec{F} = q\vec{E}$

$m\vec{a}= q  \vec{E}_0 \, cos(\omega t)$

$\vec{a}= \frac{q}{m} \vec{E}_0 \, cos(\omega t)$

$\vec{
v}(0)=0$

$\vec{v}= \frac{q}{m\omega} \vec{E}_0 \, sin(\omega t)$

This shows that the EM wave can cause a oscillatory motion by just considering the electric component, in a direction that is perpendicular to the wave vector $\vec{k}$.

**Momentum**

Momentum density of the electromagnetic field,  can be shown to be:
$\mu_0 \epsilon_0 \vec{S}$

For an electromagnetic wave
of the form

$\vec{E}_0 \, cos( \vec{k} \cdot \vec{r} -\omega t)$

The momentum density at all points in space, is in the same direction as the vector $\vec{k}$, which is the direction that the wave is moving!

So the total momentum in the electromagnetic field has zero components perpendicular to $\vec{k}$.

So how is momentum conserved if there is a momentum transfer perpendicular to $\vec{k}$ ( the one that causes perpendicular osscilations)

Specifically I would like some insight on the role of the maxwell stress tensor, $\nabla \cdot \sigma$,  in  electromagnetic momentum conservation.

**Momentum conservation in EM:**

$$\nabla \cdot \sigma - \frac{\partial \vec{p}}{\partial t} = \mu_{0} \epsilon_{0} \frac{\partial \vec{S}}{\partial t}$$

I assume its fine that the EM field momentum isn't conserved as the total momentum is, but I am still unsure what the significance of $\sigma $ is. As ignoring sigma, the law states that an increase in mechanical momentum density at a point is equal to the decrease in field momentum. $\sigma$ is known to be the momentum transport. Could this term be indicative of the EM wave generated by the charge osscilating?

Comment: "As B⃗ <<E⃗ " is not true for an EM wave.

Comment: @JerroldFranklin it is better to say that the comparison simply does not make sense in this context, since E and B do not have the same units. Per OP's equations it is vB that should be compared to E. But, regardless, the B field is still perpendicular to k... So, OP's question remains.

Comment: @jensen paull, to see how momentum is conserved for a swarm of particles in an EM field, you can look at this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/683773/conservation-of-momentum-in-electromagnetics/683793#683793. You will see that the derivation requires the field to vanish at infinity. This is not true for a plane wave (the field does not vanish at infinity), but might nevertheless be helpful for you to see where the missing momentum might come from.

Comment: You leave $\vec S$ undefined.

Comment: Congratulations, this is an interesting paradox.

Comment: I would assume that the role of the stress tensor is to blame for this "mess" as yes the field momentum has no components in the perpendicular, but if an equal and opposite momentum is created, then it should be fine.

Comment: You have ignored the contribution of magnetic field which will produce some acceleration perpendicular to $k$, but somehow managed to calculate momentum density using non zero contribution from magnetic field. Your approximation of $B<<E$ is not consistent throughout the calculation.

Comment: That wasn't my main point though, yes I have been inconsistent, but was only using that as an example that atleast one component of the resultant velocity would be perpendicular, and then comparing that to field momentum having no component in that direction

Comment: You could come up with the same "paradox" for a charge in an external electric field.  In that case the electromagnetic field momentum is zero, so how can it impart a momentum along the direction of the field?  The answer is (I think) that you need to take into account the total field configuration, including the electric and magnetic fields generated by the accelerating charge, and look at the momentum density in a region including the charge and the momentum flux out of that region.  (The latter quantity is accounted for by the stress tensor.)

Comment: I'll try to write up a more thorough answer along these lines in the coming days, if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't take into account the field produced by the charge. However even if the field has a certain momentum, ( with no component in the direction that a charge is being accelerated), although certainly non intuitive and strange, as long as the vectorial sum of mechanical and field momentum is conserved, I assume it is allowed,( as in that case the field would have  a component against the accelerated charge to balance)

Comment: @my2cts Yes interesting is also that it was asked by me and closed as duplicate two day after. Look at "How is electric field arising from photons? [duplicate]".

Comment: Thank you for reopening my question with little bit of math attached (this may keep it from censorship). Do you think that the thread 'Virtual photon description of B and E fields (2 answers)' answers it? There Lubos explains that the real field (no virtual photons) can be regarded? as virtual photons with subsequent Feynman diagrams and it explains all about EM field.

Comment: I think that if one uses scattering Feynman diagrams the momentum of electron should be perpendicular (as a mean  value) to E and B and not along E as is normal to think. By the way maybe the electron can not move with E at all. Look at my answer to the question.

Comment: Mercury, your question is a little different to mine, you were interested in the relation between classical and quantum picture of light( photons), where I am concerned with the mathematical role of the stress tensor in the context of pure EM theory alone. The electron can move with E, I have shown calculations which prove that.  Atleast in the realm of pure classical EM. Your confusion is that although the field momentum is purely in the direction of the wave vector K, you would intuitively assume, that the decrease in this momentum at a point, is equal to the increase in mechanical momentum

Comment: Momentum can also be transported, through the time derivative of the poynting vector, from the field outside the point of interest, this is where the perpendicular component comes into play, regardless of whether or not the original field momentum has a component in the perpendicular originally

Comment: @MichaelSeifert This is a paradox. No acceptable answer has been given here as yet, in spite of this being an elementary setup. Also, conservation of momentum should be a _guiding principle_, it should clarify the physics, not pose a problem itself.

Comment: I would disagree this is really a paradox, yes the momentum of the field is in a particular direction, however I would argue that this is the same scenario as an e.g "explosion", originally there are zero components of momentum in e.g the vertical, but after an explosion there is components in the vertical, whose sum is zero. There is a physical mechanism for the transfer of momentum in this way, as there is an E field in this direction. However I think the bigger picture really, is that for radiation pressure, all of the text I've seen is that they say the transfer of momentum is equal to the

Comment: Momentum of a photon. But we know from EM conservation, that the transfer of momentum isn't due to only the photons momentum, but from also the momentum flux from the field outside the point of interest

Answer (score -1):

One way to keep the EM picture and simultaneously the photon picture is the following.

The electron can not follow the oscillation of E because they are too fast and the electron has mass (there is no particle with charge without mass). So in fact it doesn't move up down. Nevertheless (here comes QM magic - I can not explain this!) the currant j associated with the electron is not 0 but has small value. Then jxB gives a force which coincides with the momentum of photons (virtual?).

Comment: I'm not bothered at the moment about the photon picture, momentum of the EM field at a point in space can be derived independently to QM. If you simply look at the lorentz force you will see there is a forward momentum transfer without the need to evoke photons, one component of which IS a perpendicular to \vec{k}. Taking the mass of an object into account, as I have done, shows there is still sinusoidal behaviour.

Comment: The main question was on the stress tensor role in conservation. As although the field momentum is only on k's direction, the transfer of momentum to matter at a point in space, can still be perpendicular

Comment: The field momentum decrease at a point in space, doesn't have to be the increase in mechanical momentum at that point in space. There is an oscillatory  motion , aswell as a forward momentum. The oscillatory component coming from the stress tensor I presume

Comment: Lets calculate approx. how much an electron will move.      \begin{aligned}dp=F\cdot t\\ mv=eEt\\ v=\dfrac{e}{m}E\dfrac{T}{2}\end{aligned}

Comment: Your math is incorrect,   look at my math in the question. Although small, it is still not zero.

Comment: Here is nothing incorect. I'm just trying to calculate and use the platform as help. Have not finished yet.

Comment: What value do you receive for Dx for a half period of of the wave? Dx=v.T appr.

Comment: "$dp= \vec{F} \cdot t$" isn't correct for this situation.  $$\int \vec{F}  dt$$ = change In momentum. By simply setting change in momentum equal to FT, you are assuming the force is constant  time, and thus any conclusions drawn from that is false.

Comment: In order to make a quick approximation I assume that E is constant during T/2.

Comment: I wouldn't obtain a dx value, I'd just solve the differential equation, as its just a simple integration

Comment: This just 2 Newton law dp=Fdt. And E is assumed constant yes for simplicity. I will get a bigger Dx. e.g. upper limit

Comment: But the force is sinusoidal, which is the furthest you can get from constant. Its easier to just solve the equation instead of overcomplicated it

Comment: No my way is much easier for getting a limit.

Comment: What is your number for dx if it is easy? I get a clear formula as upper limit for dx = the displacemet of the electron from point 0. dx=e.E.(T^2)/m.

Comment: The maximum vectorial displacement from the origin at any point in time would be. $$\frac{q\vec{E}}{m \omega^2}$$ I believe  your answer is wrong

Comment: This is the same as my easy way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134906/discussion-between-mercury-and-jensen-paull).

Comment: Mine and your equations are different.